# Unity прикрепление стрелы к объекту

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Специальная ловушка выпускает стрелу(префаб), и если она попадает в игрока, то остается на нем. Как это можно реализовать? Пробовал с помощью FixedJoint2D, но возникает 2 проблемы:
1)В скрипте стрелы пробую вставить RigidBody2D в ConnectedBody.
Если стрела соприкасается с игроком, то происходят опр. действия и

```
setJoint(rb);
    //rb это переменная в скрипте игрока, отвечающая за RigidBody2D, добавил через [SerializeField]      

       }
   }
   public void setJoint(Rigidbody2D ConObj)
   {
       joint = GetComponent<FixedJoint2D>();
       joint.connectedBody = ConObj;
   }
```

Но стрела не присоединяется, хз почему.
2) Если во время игры перетащить RigidBody с игрока на стрелу в сцене, то стрела продолжает лететь дальше, а игрок стоит на месте.

Comment: нашел по твоей теме статью [ссылка](https://gamedev.ru/unity/forum/?id=249286)

Comment: может будет выглядеть не сильно красиво но возможно самый простой способ просто сделать стрелу в момент касания дочерним к игроку и отключить ей физику (если она есть)

Comment: я так и делаю, в момент касания обнуляю скорость и вырубаю физику, но как сделать так чтобы стрела и игрок двигались вместе?